# MvvmLight bindings in code?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm-light, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to do the mvvm-light bindings in code in xamarin forms?

I want to do this to be typesafe. If so, is it possible to show me an example?

Comment: Maybe [MvvmCross](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross) would be better choice?

Comment: Hi, I tought about it but we just made the desicion to write our own mvvm frawemork :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a typesafe solution:

### In your page:

```
MyButton.SetBinding<FooViewModel>(ActivityIndicator.IsRunningProperty, model => model.IsBusy);
```

### In your FooViewModel

```
    bool _isBusy;
    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get { return _isBusy; }
        set
        {
            Set(ref _isBusy, value);
            LoginCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I've set the binding like this:

```
button.SetBinding (Button.CommandParameterProperty, "ButtonCommand");
```

Where the "ButtonCommand" is defined like this in my ViewModel:

```
public RelayCommand buttonCommand;

public RelayCommand ButtonCommand {
    get {
        ....
    }
}
```